# Express a sum of eigenvalues ​of a matrix $ A $ in terms of $ a_ {i, j} $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a problem that linear algebra that I can't verify:

> Let $A\in\mathcal{M}_{i,j}(\mathbb{K})$ a matrix, I want to prove that
>
> $$
>      \text{Tr}(AA^{t}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m} |a_{i,j}|^{2}, $$ and, if $n=m$ (this last hypothesis may not be necessary): $$
>      \text{Tr}(AA^{t}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m} |a_{i,j}|^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}^{2} $$ whit $(\lambda_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ are
> eigenvalues.

The firt equality is fulfilled due to:
\begin{equation*}
    (AA^{t})_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} a_{ik}a_{kj}.
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}
            \text{Tr}(AA^{t}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (AA^{t})_{i,i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m} a_{ik}a_{ki} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{m} |a_{ik}|^{2}.
        \end{equation*}

But the second equality I can't prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: What eigenvalues are the $\lambda_i$? If they are supposed to be the eigenvalues of $A$ this is wrong and if they are the eigenvalues of $AA^t$ it is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The value of the trace shouldn't depend on the basis used. What is obtained by using the spectral basis instead of the canonical basis?

Comment: But how do you characterize them? do you use the form $A-\lambda_{i}I$? or with $A^{2} = PDP^{-1}$

Comment: Try them both and find out!

Comment: oh i checked, i can prove that the trace of the symmetric matrix is ​​written in term of the eigenvalues :D